# Не работает функция питон, вычислить Σ

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия, return

Задания вычислить Σ

```py
import math 
k = 10
def sum(k):
  sum=0
  i=k
  for i in range(i, 12):
   sum+=(i+5)**(0.5)/(i-1)
  return sum
print(sum(k))
```

Ошибка:

line 9, in

print(non_rec_func(k))

А также:

line 7, in non_rec_func

sum+=(i+5)**0.5/(i-1)

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

После многочисленных танцев с бубнами сдался и решил попросить совет, нужно найти сумму чисел перемноженных на (i+5)**0.5/(i-1)

Числа: от k до 12

[image: Sigma]

Comment: Напишите, что вы сделать-то хотели, когда писали код? Лучше, если просто напишите задание. И что за формула sum+=(i+5)**0.5/(i-11)? Откуда она взялась?

Comment: Добавил, спасибо

Comment: а i - что такое согласно заданию?

Comment: И кроме того, теперь вы же формулу изменили и вместо 11 появилось 1. Больше ошибок нет. Т.е. это просто опечатка была, как я понимаю.

Comment: Не совсем, это практически ничего не меняет(кроме понимания что ответы были не рациональны по таким-то причинам), но он все еще странный. 
Я добавил фотку, можете посмотреть

Comment: Проверяйте. По методологии: смотрите на первую ошибку (она была в строке 7), читайте её. Там было деление на 0. Далее смотрите на знаменатель и понимаете, в чем дело.

Comment: И @Qwertiy прав про имя функции. Назовите её по-другому. Я оставил, Python позволяет, но вообще это имя встроенной функции. Может быть плохо, если где-то её используют в другом модуле по прямому назначению.

Comment: @Сергей Окей, исправлю, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убран ненужный import, исправлен крайний индекс (он не включается), убрана лишняя переменная:

```
k = 10
def sum (i):
    sum=0
    for i in range(i, 13):
        sum+=(i+5)**(0.5)/(i-1)
    return sum
print(sum(k))
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, не обижайте импорт, он нужен, но для другой задачи

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка тут -> for i in range(i, 12):
измените ПЕРВОЕ i например на s
Так верно: for s in range(i, 12):

Comment: сомневаюсь. судя по всему, простая опечатка в формуле. Она мне сразу странной показалась.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> i=k
> for i in range(i, 12):
> ```

Тут фигня. Надо от k.

И ещё мне имя ыункции не нравится.

Comment: Спасибо за напоминание про имя функции. А вот range - шире (13). Там формулу доопубликовал автор после моих вопросов типа "Что хочет Заказчик на самом деле?"